# Simple question: Finding the number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

$3$ math books, $5$ English books, $4$ science books and a dictionary are to be placed on a student's shelf so that the books of each subject remain together.

In how many different ways can the books be arranged?

$$3!\space5!\space4!\space4!$$
$3!$ ways to arrange the math books, $5$ for English, $4$ for science, and $4!$ ways to arrange all these different subject books around.

In how many of these will the dictionary be next to the maths books?

I'm not quite sure how to do the second question. Can someone please illustrate how I could find out the number of arrangements in this case.. A photo that illustrate this would be nice.. I can't quite visualize it too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the placement of subjects, there are $4$ slots that each subject can be placed in. With the added constraint that the dictionary and math books next to each other, the math books and dictionary will be considered together as a single "unit". In other words, there will be a math/dictionary slot, which along with science and English makes for a total of $3$ slots rather than $4$.

In addition, there are also 2 possible permutations among the math books and the dictionary, so the total number is:

$$3!\space5!\space4!\space3!\space2!$$

Comment: thank you very much for your reply it's a really clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have 4! ways to rearrange the books. How many ways do we have now? Since the dictionary needs to be next to the maths books we can consider them as one group with 2 arrangements (dictionary then maths or maths then dictionary). Then we have three groups to arrange (maths/dict, eng, sci) contributing a factor of 3!. So the old 4! is replaced by 2*3!

Comment: thank you very much for your reply it's a really clear explanation.

Comment: no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the subject books. There are then four possible places for the dictionary, two of which are next to the maths books.